# Images changing when I refresh page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a website for a friend that produces digital art. This person wants to have images scrolling across the screen like a marquee but with images, however, I'm running into an annoying error. Everytime I refresh the page, the images change. Sometimes its how It's how I want it to be but sometimes it's wrong.

These are the images that im talking about:

The incorrect one
[image]

The correct one
[image]

You can see for yourself on my website: https://www.kevs.website/art/

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="preve">
    <img src="images/image0.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image0.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" class="preveimg">
</div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.preveimg {
height: 493.150685px;
width: 500px;
animation: sc-left 20s linear infinite;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

`}`

```
.preve {
display: flex;
```

`}`

Code may be amateur because I only started a while ago.

This only occurs when I host it on a website.
When I open it from the file explorer everything works fine which confuses me because should'nt they be the same?

Comment: Looks like a problem with flex processing the img width

Comment: `background-repeat` and `background-size` are not necessary here, those properties would only be used if you were setting the images as a `background-image` of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from a mix of `display: flex` trying to squeeze all your images in the screen-wide `.preve` div, and the `width` CSS property and/or the fact your images are taking time to load due to their weight.

In order to solve your case, I just added `flex-shrink: 0` it tells `flex` not to squeeze the content and keep its actual size.

```css
.preve {
  display: flex;
}

.preveimg {
  height: 493.150685px;
  width: 500px;
  animation: sc-left 20s linear infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  flex-shrink: 0; //Just added this, seems to work out
}

@keyframes sc-left {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-400%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="preve">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image0.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image1.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image2.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image3.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image0.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image1.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image2.jpg" class="preveimg">
    <img src="https://www.kevs.website/art/images/image3.jpg" class="preveimg">
</div>
```

### Alternative

If this does not work out, adding `min-width: 500px;` seems to work too but as this is not a flex-relative property, it may cause side-effects.

Comment: @Kev If your problem got solved, you can mark the answer as accepted so other users having the same problem will see it has been resolved. Check the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more and eventually the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Also consider upvoting this answer :) Good luck on your project ! ;)